# php mailer fue axctualizado o algo?

Tags: php

tengo una web para enviar correo pero confifuro el Php y no me envia los correos este es el codigo que me da de error:

**Código de activación no fue enviado. Error de Correo: Falló la siguiente dirección de correo electrónico: shaiyarewards2019@gmail.com: CORREO no aceptado del servidor, 530,5.5.1 Se requiere autenticación. Obtenga más información en 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError w62sm21088070qkd.30 - gsmtp
Error del servidor SMTP: 5.5.1 Se requiere autenticación. Obtenga más información en 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError w62sm21088070qkd.30 - gsmtp
Error del servidor SMTP: 5.5.1 Se requiere autenticación. Obtenga más información en 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError w62sm21088070qkd.30 - gsmtp**

y este el archivo php

```
    <?php 
$ServerName = "shaiyarewards.com"; 
//SMTP Auth 
$SMTPAuth = true; 
// SMTP Server Address 
$SMTP = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
// SMTP Server Port 
$PORT = 587; 
// SMTP Secure tls/ssl 
$SMTPS = "tls"; 
// SMTP Username 
$SMTPUSR = "shai123456@gmail.com"; 
// SMTP Password
$SMTPPASS = "123456789"; 
// From Address 
$From = "shai123456@gmail.com"; $basepath="http://158.69.30.94:8080/images/images.jpg"; 
$max_slot = 240;

    ?>
```

Como corrijo ese problema? creo he configurado bien el PhP pero no envia los correos.

NOTA Obviamente no es un correo real si no de mentira que coloque como ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

para usar php mailer a través de gmail debes de dar Acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras

[Acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

Comment: eso esta hecho el detalle que sigue dando el mismo error